# How to dynamically bind value (Options) to Dropdown - Office UI Fabric React Components

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, office-ui-fabric-react

I'm using Office UI Fabric React dropdown in my spfx webpart. I have added static options in that dropdown as below, but I want to bind options dynamically which i'm getting from REST api.

```
<Dropdown
placeholder="Select"
label="Select Location (Lookup)"
id="ddlLocation"
options={[                       
    { key: 'A', text: 'Option a' },
    { key: 'B', text: 'Option b' },
    { key: 'D', text: 'Option d' },
    { key: 'E', text: 'Option e' }                      
]}
```

If I'm not wrong then we have to pass function in options parameter which will return data in that format. If any one know then please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Init a property, which stores your options inside component's class:

```
private options: any[] = [];
```

Then load options dynamically (it depends on your application's logic), for example using async http function, you can init options in componentDidMount:

```
public async componentDidMount(): Promise<void> {
    this.categories = await SpService.getAllCategories();

    this.options = [];
    this.categories.forEach(c => {
      this.options.push({
        key: c.id,
        text: c.title
      });
    });
  }
```

In `render`:

```
<Dropdown
    label='Category:'
    options={this.options}
    errorMessage={this.categoryError}
    onChanged={this.onCategoryChanged}
/>
```

To make it work you should also trigger component re-render after async data is received. If you don't do it, then move `options` property to a state and call `this.setState` from `componentDidMount` method.
That way you can initialize your options with some dynamic async data.

Comment: It works ! Thanks a lots Sergei for your quick help :-)

Comment: It worked to me as well.